# Can I submit a new version of an app to the App Store if the current version is available for sale, but not public yet?

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store

I've never been in this specific situation before.

I submitted an app that successfully passed Apple's review process. The app now is now in **Ready for Sale** status, but I have yet to release the app to the public (for various reasons I don't want to get into). It is the first version of the app, so the app isn't available to the public in any form just yet.

If I have a followup version done and ready for submission, can I submit it for review changing the release date of the submitted version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the Ready for Sale state, you should be able to Remove the app from sale.

[Remove App from Sale](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW35)

You can then create your new version and submit for review.  The first version should never hit the App Store since it's state will be "Developer removed from sale".

Comment: No no, not trying to remove the app. 

I'm just withholding the release of this app for a little bit longer for a few reasons. 

I have the next build ready to be reviewed, and I want to launch the first version while the second version is part-way through the review process. 

I was wondering if I can have the second one enter review while the first one retains 'Ready for Sale' status.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between removing the app from sale and deleting the app altogether. Removing the app from sale means that it no longer shows up in the App Store, but can be put back into the App Store at a later time. I think this is the only way you can achieve what you are looking to do outside of having a talk with Apple.  You definitely do not want to "Delete the App", as that will get rid of it completely.